# Django/Python imports from different django projects with the same app name and same model name

Tags: django, importerror

My django project structure is as follows:

main/

```
project_A/
 apps/
    account
       models.py
       views.py
       urls.py
       __init__.py
    purchase
       models.py
       views.py
       urls.py
       __init__.py
   …..

project_B/
 apps/
    account
      models.py
      views.py
      urls.py
      __init__.py
    signups
      models.py
      views.py
      urls.py
      __init__.py
   ….
```

Under my main/ workspace, I have two separate django projects, called 'Project_A' and 'Project_B'. Each project has its own set of apps.   Each project has an app called 'account'. (same app name across different django projects).  I need to get the two projects to talk to each other, for which I need to perform the following import in views.py of the 'purchase' app in Project_A

from project_B.apps.account.models import Account

(Here Account is a model in the models.py of the account app. Same model and app name in two different django projects)

However, it looks like based on the way the import is working; from within Project_A, the above import essentially resolves to:

from account.models import Account  (it resolves to the Account model from the models.py for the account app for Project_A.)   However, I need to import from Project_B.   How can I get this to work?

Django version:1.3
Python version 2.7.2
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: ***WWWWWHHHHYYYYYY??????!!!!!!!***

Comment: I need to query some fields from the account model from Project_B in Project_A;  hence, I need to import the account model from Project_B in Project A.

Comment: Honestly, you should put all your apps into one single project, giving them different names. Your setup is totally weird and doesn't look like a good concept.

Comment: Project_A is for sellers and Project_B is for buyers. Keeping the projects separate made it really easy for user management, as I do not have to keep track of whether a user is a buyer or a seller (as these have their own separate 'accounts' in the separate projects.

Comment: Still, this is not a good idea. You have to replicate project settings and you cannot run both projects on the same server. As you can see from your problem above, this is not the way Django projects are supposed to work. Put everything in one project and find other ways of dealing with sellers and buyers.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving alias via Python keyword `as`. Take a look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import)

Example:

```
from project_B.apps.account.models import Account as Account_b
```

Comment: Since the import first looks in the current directory, and django's get_model() returns the Account model from the account app from Project A, the above solution did not work for me.  I tried relative imports as well as:

from ..Project_B.apps.account.models import Account

This did not work as well.